# Creating a startup

Tags: programmer, project-management, software

So I have numerous app and tech ideas that I really want to pursue. I have knowledge in python and some in Swift and know a lot about entrepreneurship and efficiency. How do I go about getting a group of members together for no pay, but a share of the profit if we receive any. I've failed with trying to draw people in because the sound of "no pay" puts a lot of people off that they don't want to hear the idea.

Thanks,

Colin

Comment: Get a prototype with your own money and then find investors. This is the only alternative if you do not find anyone to work for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I go about getting a group of members together for no pay, but
>   a share of the profit if we receive any.

Realistically, you either

- bring along a bunch of close friends who are experts in the field and passionate enough about the idea to take a huge financial risk on it,
- "hire" some naïve and incompetent college students and string them along until the whole thing falls apart

Unless it's a close personal friend, nobody with real skills and experience is going to accept a job solely on the possibility of maybe getting some profit share some day if you actually make any profit. People with the skills and experience you need to get your start-up off the ground are going to expect to be paid for education and experience they bring to the team. Asking them to work for free is disrespectful of their skills.

The business model you are proposing is the *number one red flag* to look out for when interviewing with a client. It shows that the client is

- Too inexperienced to be running a business (or otherwise trying to exploit freelancers)
- Not confident in the success of their idea (if they were, they'd want all of the profit!)

If you're the one starting the business, you're supposed to be the one taking the risk. If your idea is so great, then you **take a business loan and use that to pay your employees or freelancers**. If you can't get a business loan, it indicates that your idea isn't that great, or that you don't have the experience you need to be running the business in the first place.

Comment: Hey I really appreciated the help, thanks a lot.

Comment: @C.Forrest I'm glad to have helped. Would you care to mark it as the answer if it resolved your question?